# Using @Polymer/app-storage with lit-element

Tags: polymer, web-component, indexeddb, lit-element

I want to use indexedDB with lit-element. To do so, I imported @polymer/app-storage/app-indexeddb-mirror in my lit-element project.
A copy of my code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/indexeddb-and-lit-element?file=package.json).
The value in the data attribute is not saved to indexedDB. No error is thrown.

Is there any incompatibility between the @polymer webcomponents and lit-element ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `<app-indexeddb-mirror>` is just a web component, you can use it's API in any DOM-friendly library, including in lit-html.

For example:

```js
  render() {
    return html`
      <app-indexeddb-mirror
            key="indexKey"
            data="${this.data}"
            @persisted-data-changed="${this.persistedDataChanged}">
            log
        </app-indexeddb-mirror>
    `;
  }
```

Note that lit-html has a different syntax for binding event listeners to element.s whereas with Polymer templates, you might add an attribute like

```js
static get template() {
  return html`<input on-change="methodName">`
}
```

With lit-html, the syntax for binding an event listener uses `@` in place of `on-`, and does not automatically dash-case your event names, so you could use:

```js
html`<my-el @eventName="${referenceToFunction}"></my-el>`
```

where `referenceToFunction` is a direct reference to the event handler.

Note also that you don't need to create a lambda expression to pass the event to the instance method, since lit-html will auto-bind that function for you.

That all being said, consider using something like [KV-Storage](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/kv-storage), [idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) or [idb-keyval](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb-keyval) for simpler cases, as you'll end up shipping much less JavaScript to your clients that way, since you won't have to shlep along the entire Polymer library with you.